# SQL Server Nested Triggers not firing as expected

Tags: sql-server, triggers, powerbuilder

I have upgraded a SQL Server 6.5 database to SQL Server 2012 by scripting the schema from 6.5, fixing any syntax issues in this script and then I have used this script to create a 2012 database.

At the same time I have upgraded the front-end application from PowerBuilder 6 to 12.5.

When I perform a certain action in the application it inserts data in to a given table.  This table has a trigger associated with the INSERT action and within this trigger other tables are updated.  This causes additional triggers to fire on these tables as well.

Initially the PowerBuilder application reports the following error:

Row changed between retrieve and update.

No changes made to database.

Now I understand what this error message means but this is where it gets really 'interesting'!

In order to understand what is happening in the triggers I decided to insert data in to a logging table from within the triggers so that I could better understand the flow of events.  This had a rather unexpected side effect - the PowerBuilder application no longer reports any errors and when I check in the database all data is written away as expected.

If I remove these lines of logging, the application once again fails with the error message previously listed.

My question is - Can anyone explain why adding some lines of logging could possibly have this side effect?  It almost seems like the act of adding some logging which write data away to a logging table, slows things down or somehow serializes the triggers to fire in the correct order....

Thanks in advance for any insight you can offer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's recap why this message comes up (I have a longer explanation at http://www.techno-kitten.com/PowerBuilder_Help/Troubleshooting/Database_Irregularities/database_irregularities.html). It's basically because the database can no longer find the data it's trying to UPDATE, based on the WHERE clause generated by the DataWindow. Triggers cause this by changing data in columns in the updated table, so logic of WHERE = fails.

If I were troubleshooting this, I'd do the following for both versions of the trigger:

- retrieve your data in the app, and also in a DBMS tool, cache the data from both (data from the Original buffer in PB, debugger breakpoint in PB may help) and compare the columns you expect to be in the WHERE clause (client side manipulation of data and status flags can also cause this problem)
- make your data changes and initiate the save
- from a breakpoint in the SQLPreview events (this is likely multiple rows if it's trigger-caused), cache the pending UPDATE statements
- while still paused in SQLPreview, use the WHERE clause in the UPDATE statements to SELECT the data with the DBMS tool

Somewhere through all this, you'll identify where the process is breaking down in the failure case, and figure out why it passes in the good case. I suspect you'll find a much simpler solution than you're hypothesizing.

Good luck,

Terry

Comment: Many thanks for the tips Terry.  It turns out the problem related to how PowerBuilder 12.5 deals with the Row Counts returned.  As there are a series of cascading triggers associated with the INSERT many different row counts are returned.  These were filtered out in PB 6.5 but not in 12.5.  Setting the RecheckRows DBParm resolved this issue.